# How to interpret this statement consisting of multiple commas?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am trying to interpret this sentence which was taken from a legal document:

> "You are not eligible if you are, or were at the time you acquired the
>   original information provided to the Company, a member, officer, or
>   employee of the Company."

I have seen two ways of interpreting the sentence above:

> 1)  You are not eligible if you are currently an employee of the
>   Company, or you were an employee during the time you acquired the
>   original information (emphasis is on employment at company).
>
> 2)  You are not eligible if you are or were an employee of the company at the time you acquired the original information (emphasis on the time the original information was acquired).

Which interpretation is correct?  Or is there room for both interpretations to be correct?

Thank you very much!

Sincerely,

Eric

Comment: Your first example is better but please, what exactly did you find unclear about the original text?

Comment: Also please notice the huge difference between a "statement consisting of multiple commas" which that is not, and a "statement containing multiple commas" which that is…

Comment: I agree with both of @RobbieGoodwin's comments.  Your first interpretation agrees with the original in that current employees are ineligible, regardless of when they acquired the information. The most natural reading of your second interpretation disagrees with the original in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

The first is definitely a correct interpretation.

Under 2, you seem to be suggesting it does not refer to someone who is currently an employee, but who wasn't at the time they acquired the information. I do not think that is a validly correct understanding of the sentence. If that were the case, why would the present tense ***are*** be used? Only ***were*** would be needed.

The comma after *are* and the one after *Company* are clearly parenthetical. So if you remove the words between those commas it says:

***You are not eligible if you are...a member, officer, or employee of the Company.***

Comment: So much better than those invalidly correct understandings.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if the "original information you have acquired was provided to the Company during a time in which you were either a member, officer, or employee of the Company, then you are not eligible."

Answer (score 0):

This is badly drafted, and it's the kind of things that sometimes gets settled in court, the presence or absence of the comma notwithstanding. Emphasis isn't the issue here, but how to interpret the restriction about the time of acquisition of the information. If the restriction applies only to former employees, then all current employees are ineligible whether or not they ever acquired the information. If the restriction applies to everyone, then those whose employment coincided with their acquisition of the information are ineligible.